# Is Android SDK Level 26 supported for use with Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, android-8.0-oreo

The [latest Appcelerator docs](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_safe-id-VGl0YW5pdW1Db21wYXRpYmlsaXR5TWF0cml4LUFuZHJvaWRTREsvVGFyZ2V0QW5kcm9pZHBsYXRmb3Jt) seems to indicate that the max supported version of the Android SDK is Level 26 for Android target version 8.x Oreo.

So I opened Android Studio and uninstalled all other Android SDK Levels per screenshot below, and installed 26:

[image: Android Studio]

However, now when I try to run my app on Android 8.0 (Oreo) emulator via Appcelerator Studio I get the following error:

> [ERROR] :  Unable to find a suitable installed Android SDK that is API >=23 and <=25

When I run `appc info` from the command line I get this message:

> !  Android API Android 8.0.0 (android-26) is too new and may or may
>   not work with Titanium SDK
>        7.1.0.
>        The maximum supported Android API level by Titanium SDK 7.1.0 is API level 25.

This seems to contradict the documentation. If Android SDK Level 26 is not supported, then is using Level 25 adequate for building apps that will run on Android 8.0 Oreo?

Here is tooling I have running:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.13.3
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 9.4.0
  npm Version                 = 5.6.0
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 7.1.0.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/.../Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.1.0.GA
  Target Platform             = android
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be supported. I use Titanium SDK 7.1.0 GA with Android API 26 (8.0) and can compile correctly. Maybe you need to change your Android manifest inside the tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: One more question - I tried similar setup for Android SDK 27 (android:targetSdkVersion="27") after uninstalling SDK 26 and installing SDK 27 in Android Studio.  Any idea if it is possible to build the app using Android SDK 27?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's mandatory to have SDK 26 installed even though you target SDK 27 when building on Titanium 7.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported already, but has not received the whole regression testing so far. Official support if planned for 7.2.0 as part of [TIMOB-25852](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25852) which will support targets from 23 to 27. Note: This does not influence the minimum target, which will still remain Android 4.1 (API 16).